# Is there a non-deprecated equivalent of rfc822.AddressList?

Tags: python, email, rfc822, email-parsing

I need something like rfc822.AddressList to parse, say, the content of the "TO" header field of an email into individual addresses.  Since rfc822 is deprecated in favor of the email package, I looked for something similar there but couldn't find anything.  Does anyone know what I'm supposed to use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh it's email.utils.getaddresses.  Just make sure to call it with a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a third party module, I ported the Python 2.x module rfc822 to Python 3.x

https://github.com/MarkNenadov/rfc822py3

It hasn't been tested thoroughly yet. I encourage you to try it out and let me know how it works and whether you have any problems.

To make your code work in both Python 2 and 3 you can take my rfc822py3 module and do:

```
try:
   import rfc822
except ImportError:
   import rfc822py3 as rfc822
```